# Web application design that is independent of servlets (uses Web server no application server )

Tags: java, webserver, lighty

I am trying to architect a web application that requires real time push (perhaps websockets) but I am constrained by memory and would like to avoid the us of a servlet container. So to say that my application would be deployed on a web server ONLY (no interfacing application server) and should be able to communicate with the services (preferably java based)
What are my choices of the 
- Web UI library (Id love to use GWT but not sure how feasible that would be)
- Services backend
- real time push

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a light weight push notification system that runs on webserver only. Try Atmosphere Framework http://async-io.org.

To answer your question related to Memory constraint

1) Decouple and create a seperate push-server based on atmosphere
2) Whenever your application services is ready with data to push, Push it to the decoupled push server. Pushing it can be acieved through either JMS or Asynchttpclient 
3) Your browser client will always listen to the de-coupled push server.

Let me know if you need more help.